# Given a 2D character array find all paths from the top left to the the bottom right

Tags: algorithm, recursion, big-o, dynamic-programming

Given a 2D character array find all possible paths from the top left corner to the bottom right corner. I have the following recursive solution. Could someone explain how to find the complexity of it? Also, is there a more optimal solution? I am not too familiar with Dynamic Programming, but I think it can somehow be used to solve this problem.

```
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>> getPaths(char [][]grid){
        return getPaths(grid, 0, 0, new ArrayList<Character>());
    }

    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>> getPaths(char [][]grid, int x, int y, ArrayList<Character> path){
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>> allPaths = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>>();
        path.add(grid[x][y]);

        ArrayList<Character> path1 = new ArrayList<Character>(path);
        ArrayList<Character> path2 = new ArrayList<Character>(path);
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>> val1, val2;
        if(x == grid.length-1 && y == grid[0].length-1){
            allPaths.add(path);
        }
        else{
            if(x < grid.length-1){
                val1 = getPaths(grid, x+1, y, path1);
                for(ArrayList<Character> v1: val1)
                    allPaths.add(v1);
            }
            if(y < grid[0].length-1){
                val2 = getPaths(grid, x, y+1, path2);
                for(ArrayList<Character> v2: val2)
                    allPaths.add(v2);
            }
        }  
        return allPaths;
    }
```

Comment: Your description is a bit lacking - are you looking for _all paths_ or _all shortest paths_? And the 2D character array, what does it represent? does it represent a map with obstacles? otherwise you just need the dimensions of the grid (ie. start coordinates and end coordinates)

Comment: I just want to return all possible paths where a person can only move right or down at from a given point in the 2D array. Not the shortest path. The indexes in the array do not represent obstacles, they represent a step int the path.

Answer (score 1):

If your allowed moves are only down or right, one more way to think about this could be all permutations of `y-1` `down`'s and `x-1` `right`'s. For example, a 4x3 grid would be:

```
ddrrr
drdrr
drrdr
...
rrrdd
```

In that case, if you prefer, rather than recursion, you could use any number of algorithms that produce the "next lexicographic permutation" (in this case the string can also be converted to binary) to generate the path-maps. To generate the actual path, you would start at (0,0) and update x and y according to whether the character is indicating down or right.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by "all possible paths" you mean moving only left and down, right? That's what your code seems to indicate. Also important: are you trying to find the paths, or just count them?

You're branching twice at almost every iteration, so I'd say this is 2^n. But the size of your answer is also going to be 2^n relative to the size of the grid.

Here's how you should think of optimizing this: Imagine an arbitrary square in the middle of the grid. It has some number of paths leading *from* it and some number of paths leading *to* it. Currently, if you approach a square you've already approached before, you are calculating all possible exit paths from that square *again*.  Instead, for each square, once its exit paths are calculated, you should then store all those paths associated with that square in memory, so that the next time an entry path finds its way to that square, you don't need to recurse again - you can just loop through all the exit paths and attach the current entry path to them.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization

Comment: 2^n? It's an MxN array though

Comment: Try drawing it out.  It's definitely exponential.

Comment: Consider "n" to mean "x*y." (So "n" is "number of squares" - your problem size)

(2x2) -> 4 squares -> 2 paths

(2,3) or (3,2) -> 6 squares -> 3 paths

(3,3) -> 9 squares -> 6 paths

(3,4) -> 12 squares -> 10 paths

(4,4) -> 16 squares ->

Answer (score 0):

1) Your solution searches paths moving only left and down, and since there can be infinity number of paths if any directions and any loops are allowed I suppose it's right.

2) Time Complexity:
It seems you generate each node for each path exactly once and total number of operation is proportional to total path count multiplied by paths length. All paths have the same length (M + N). Also we can construct recursive formula for paths count:

K(M , N) = K(M - 1, N) + K(M, N - 1)

K(1, * ) = K( * , 1) = 1

You may notice that it's very similar to recursive formula for binomial coefficient so we can conclude that:

K(M, N) ~ C(M + N, N)

More exactly:

K(M, N) = C(M + N - 2, N - 1) = C(M + N - 2, M - 1);  K(0, 0) = 0;

You can check how this equation transforms recursive formula for path count to one for binomial coefficient and back, and also it's may be easier to understand  looking how this numbers are arranged on Pascal's tree.
So we can conclude that time complexity is O(C(M + N, N) * (M + N))

3) Obviously you can't generate all paths asymptotically faster since result's size has  the same complexity, but may be you can reach a bit better performance if you will not generate all subpaths again when you pass through the same character, it's may be not easy to make recursively but you can loop through diagonal starting from bottom right character and passing generated subpaths one to top adjacent and one copy to the left adjacent character. But as I said, it will not be sufficiently better since copying may be faster than generating, but not asymptotically in this case.

Comment: Here is very similar task where O(N*M) can be achieved , you can look through my examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095198/finding-snake-sequence-in-xy-graph-java