# Finding snake sequence in XY graph - Java

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I am working on a problem to try to find what is called a Snake Sequence in a typical XY graph (aka grid). A Snake sequence is defined as a sequence of numbers where each new number, which can only be located to the right or down of the current number, is either plus or minus one. For example, if you are in the center of the graph, you can either move right (if that number is + or - 1) or move down (if that number is + or - 1). The goal of the problem is to find the longest path (aka Snake Sequence) through the graph (keeping in mind you can only chart a path to a new cell whose value is +- 1 with the current cell).

So, for the following XY graph, the longest snake sequence is: `9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 6, 7`

```
9, 6, 5, 2
8, 7, 6, 5
7, 3, 1, 6
1, 1, 1, 7
```

Below is my code, which does not seem to work.

**Question:** How would you solve this problem above? (I offer my code showing what I have thus far, but it does not work)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SnakeSequence {
  private final int maxX = 3;
  private final int maxY = 3;
  private final int[][] board = new int[][]{
      {1, 2, 3, 4},
      {2, 1, -1, 5},
      {3, 0, -1, 6},
      {6, 2, 1, 7}
  };

  private ArrayList<Integer> findSequence(int xPos,
      int yPos, ArrayList<Integer> currentPath) {
    currentPath.add(board[yPos][xPos]);

    ArrayList<Integer> pathRight = new ArrayList<Integer>(currentPath);
    ArrayList<Integer> pathDown = new ArrayList<Integer>(currentPath);

    if (xPos < maxX || yPos < maxY) {
      if (yPos < maxY && (board[yPos + 1][xPos] + 1 == board[yPos][xPos] ||
                          board[yPos + 1][xPos] - 1 == board[yPos][xPos])) {
        pathDown = findSequence(xPos, yPos + 1, currentPath);
      }
      if (xPos < maxX && (board[yPos][xPos + 1] + 1 == board[yPos][xPos] ||
                          board[yPos][xPos + 1] - 1 == board[yPos][xPos])) {
        pathRight = findSequence(xPos + 1, yPos, currentPath);
      }

      if (pathDown.size() > pathRight.size()) {
        return pathDown;
      } else {
        return pathRight;
      }
    }
    return currentPath;
  }

  private void getSequence() {
    ArrayList<Integer> currentPath = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> result;
    result = findSequence(0, 0, currentPath);

    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
      System.out.println(result.get(i));
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SnakeSequence sequence = new SnakeSequence();
    sequence.getSequence();
  }
}
```

Comment: Am I the only one who is missing your question?

Comment: @ZerO - Thanks for your comment. I have tried to clarify the question more to make it clear exactly what I am asking.

Comment: You probably want to be using DP to solve this, and your solution should run in time O(number of cells in grid).

Comment: What is an XY graph? Do you mean a grid?

Answer (score 2):

You can imagine your table as an [oriented graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph), then you problem is just to find the [longest path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem).

Fortunatly for you, only moving down and right is allowed, so your graph is [acyclic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), so you can use algorithms like [critical path method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_path_method).

This is how your graph would look like:

[image: graph image]

However, you want to find longest path between *any* two cells. To do that, I would compute for each cell the longest path starting at that cell. It is simmilar to what you do, but you compute same thing more times. Consider this:

```
6 -> 5
|    |
v    v
7 -> 6
```

At both `5` and `7` you compute how long is the path from `6` at down right, and that is useless repeated computation. In worst case scenario, this could lead to exponential time consumption, while the problem can be resolved in linear time!

Moreover, there is no guarantee that the longest path will start at `(0,0)`.

(one possible) **Solution:**

Compute longest path from each cell, starting from bottom-right to upper-left. At each cel.. remember how long the longest path from that cell is, and witch way from that cell the path leads. (I will measure path length by number of cells on it). So for example, for the only `8` in your grapth, we would remeber `[length=8, direction=right]`.

*Why so complicated?* Because it is now extramly easy to compute longest path at a cell, if we know the longest path of the cells to the right and down. Example (I made up):

[image: longest path choosing]

The correct data for `2` now would be `[length=4, direction=down]` because can't go from `2` to `4`.

You can also keep globally longest path and it's start. After the computation is complete, just walk the longest path from that start through the `direction` and write the numbers, position or whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for my Java (I am primarily a c# programmer) but here is one solution.  I separated out the algorithm that discovers the snakes from the algorithm (implementing the interface ISnakeProcessor) that processes each one.  That way you could enhance the code to, e.g., collect the snake with the largest sum of values, or collect all the longest snakes, in case there are more than one, by adding more ISnakeProcessor classes.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Rextester
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SnakeSequence sequence = new SnakeSequence();
        sequence.getSequence();
    }
}

interface ISnakeProcessor
{
    void process(List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> snake);
}

class SnakeSequence {

    private final int[][] board;

    public SnakeSequence()
    {
        this(new int[][]{
            {1, 2, 3, 4},
            {2, 1, -1, 5},
            {3, 0, -1, 6},
            {6, 2, 1, 7}
        });
    }

    public SnakeSequence(int[][] board)
    {
        this.board = board;
    }

    public boolean isValid(int iRow, int iCol)
    {
        if (iRow < 0 || iRow >= board.length)
            return false;
        if (iCol < 0 || iCol >= board[iRow].length)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    private boolean continuesInRow(int iRow, int iCol)
    {
        if (!isValid(iRow, iCol) || !isValid(iRow+1, iCol))
            return false;
        int myVal = board[iRow][iCol];
        if (board[iRow+1][iCol] == myVal - 1 || board[iRow+1][iCol] == myVal + 1)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    private boolean continuesInCol(int iRow, int iCol)
    {
        if (!isValid(iRow, iCol) || !isValid(iRow, iCol+1))
            return false;
        int myVal = board[iRow][iCol];
        if (board[iRow][iCol+1] == myVal - 1 || board[iRow][iCol+1] == myVal + 1)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isHead(int iRow, int iCol)
    {
        if (!isValid(iRow, iCol))
            return false;
        if (isValid(iRow-1, iCol) && continuesInRow(iRow-1, iCol))
            return false;
        if (isValid(iRow, iCol-1) && continuesInRow(iRow, iCol-1))
            return false;
        return true;            
    }

    private boolean isTail(int iRow, int iCol)
    {
        if (!isValid(iRow, iCol))
            return false;
        if (continuesInRow(iRow, iCol))
            return false;
        if (continuesInCol(iRow, iCol))
            return false;
        return true;
    }        

    private void testHead() 
    {
        System.out.println("Dumping list of heads");
        for (int iRow = 0; iRow < board.length; iRow++) 
        {
            for (int iCol = 0; iCol < board[iRow].length; iCol++) 
            {
                boolean head = isHead(iRow, iCol);
                boolean tail = isTail(iRow, iCol);
                if (head && tail)
                    System.out.print("  B");
                else if (head)
                    System.out.print("  H");
                else if (tail)
                    System.out.print("  T");
                else
                    System.out.print("  -");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    private void walkSnake(ISnakeProcessor processor, int iRow, int iCol, ArrayList<Pair<Integer, Integer>> snake)
    {
        snake.add(new Pair<Integer, Integer>(iRow, iCol));

        boolean isTail = true;
        if (continuesInRow(iRow, iCol))
        {
            walkSnake(processor, iRow+1, iCol, snake);
            isTail = false;
        }
        if (continuesInCol(iRow, iCol)) 
        {
            walkSnake(processor, iRow, iCol+1, snake);
            isTail = false;
        }
        if (isTail)
        {
            processor.process(snake);
        }
        snake.remove(snake.size() - 1);
    }

    private void walkSnakes(ISnakeProcessor processor)
    {
        ArrayList<Pair<Integer, Integer>> snake = new ArrayList<Pair<Integer, Integer>>();
        for (int iRow = 0; iRow < board.length; iRow++) 
            for (int iCol = 0; iCol < board[iRow].length; iCol++)
                if (isHead(iRow, iCol))
                    walkSnake(processor, iRow, iCol, snake);                
    }

    class LongestSnakeFinder implements ISnakeProcessor
    {
        private final SnakeSequence parent;
        ArrayList<Pair<Integer, Integer>> longest = new ArrayList<Pair<Integer, Integer>>();

        public LongestSnakeFinder(SnakeSequence parent) 
        {
            this.parent = parent;
        }

        public void process(List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> snake)
        {
            if (snake.size() > longest.size())
            {
                longest.clear();
                longest.addAll(snake);
            }
        }

        public void dumpLongest()
        {
            System.out.format("The first encountered longest snake has length %d:\n", longest.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < longest.size(); i++)
            {
                int iRow = longest.get(i).getFirst();
                int iCol = longest.get(i).getSecond();
                System.out.format("   (%d,%d): %d\n", iRow, iCol, parent.getValue(iRow, iCol));
            }
        }
    }

    public int getNRows() { return board.length; }

    public int getNCols(int iRow) { return board[iRow].length; }

    public int getValue(int iRow, int iCol) { return board[iRow][iCol]; }

    public void getSequence() {
        testHead();
        LongestSnakeFinder finder = new LongestSnakeFinder(this);
        walkSnakes(finder);
        finder.dumpLongest();
    }
}

class Pair<F, S> {
    private F first; //first member of pair
    private S second; //second member of pair

    public Pair(F first, S second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public F getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public S getSecond() {
        return second;
    }
}
```

Example run here: http://rextester.com/AKUFNL43897
Update - cleaned code a little.  New sample run here: http://rextester.com/AVOAIY11573

And, the output:

```
Dumping list of heads
  H  -  -  -
  -  -  B  -
  T  -  T  -
  B  H  T  T
The first encountered longest snake has length 7:
   (0,0): 1
   (0,1): 2
   (0,2): 3
   (0,3): 4
   (1,3): 5
   (2,3): 6
   (3,3): 7
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: didnt look at your code, but your result seems not to fit with eb80 expectations. 1-2-1-2-3-4-5-6-7 should be found with yout imput and his definition

Comment: @skoll - In the sequence "1212", to reach the second "2" you would need to step upwards, from row 1 to row 0.  The requirement stated new number "can only be located to the right or down of the current number."

Answer (score 0):

Here is one simple way to correct your solution and avoid copying of path on every step

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class SnakeSequence {
  private final int maxX = 3;
  private final int maxY = 3;
  private final int[][] board = new int[][]{
      {1, 2, 3, 4},
      {2, 1, -1, 5},
      {3, 0, -1, 6},
      {6, 2, 1, 7}
  };

  private ArrayList<Integer> findSequence(int xPos,
      int yPos) {    

      ArrayList<Integer> pathRight = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      ArrayList<Integer> pathDown = new ArrayList<Integer>();    

      if (yPos < maxY && (board[yPos + 1][xPos] + 1 == board[yPos][xPos] ||
                          board[yPos + 1][xPos] - 1 == board[yPos][xPos])) {
        pathDown = findSequence(xPos, yPos + 1);
      }
      if (xPos < maxX && (board[yPos][xPos + 1] + 1 == board[yPos][xPos] ||
                          board[yPos][xPos + 1] - 1 == board[yPos][xPos])) {
        pathRight = findSequence(xPos + 1, yPos);
      }
      ArrayList<Integer> ans; 
      if (pathDown.size() > pathRight.size()) {
          ans = pathDown;
      } else {
          ans = pathRight;
      }
      ans.add(board[yPos][xPos]);
      return ans;    
  }

  private void getSequence() {
     ArrayList<Integer> result;
     result = findSequence(0, 0);
     Collections.reverse(result);
     for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
       System.out.println(result.get(i));
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SnakeSequence sequence = new SnakeSequence();
    sequence.getSequence();

  }
}
```

But this way it can work much faster for big arrays due to no recalculating the longest path every time you visiting the same number during recursion. Actually, in this version each number is visited at most twice. It's achieved through saving best solution for every node. Separate storage of path and it length allows not to copy path when it's not needed.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class SnakeSequence {
  private final int maxX = 3;
  private final int maxY = 3;
  private final int[][] board = new int[][]{
      {1, 2, 3, 4},
      {2, 3, -1, 5},
      {3, 2, -1, 6},
      {6, 1, 2, 3}
  };    
  int[][] pathLength;
  ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>> paths;

  private ArrayList<Integer> findSequence(int xPos,
      int yPos) { 
      if(pathLength[yPos][xPos] >= 0)
      {
          ArrayList<Integer> ans = new ArrayList<Integer>();
          int length =  pathLength[yPos][xPos];
          ArrayList<Integer> path = paths.get(yPos).get(xPos);
          for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
              ans.add(path.get(i));
          return ans;
      }

      ArrayList<Integer> pathRight = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      ArrayList<Integer> pathDown = new ArrayList<Integer>();

      if (yPos < maxY && (board[yPos + 1][xPos] + 1 == board[yPos][xPos] ||
                          board[yPos + 1][xPos] - 1 == board[yPos][xPos])) {
        pathDown = findSequence(xPos, yPos + 1);
      }
      if (xPos < maxX && (board[yPos][xPos + 1] + 1 == board[yPos][xPos] ||
                          board[yPos][xPos + 1] - 1 == board[yPos][xPos])) {
        pathRight = findSequence(xPos + 1, yPos);
      }
      ArrayList<Integer> ans; 
      if (pathDown.size() > pathRight.size()) {
          ans = pathDown;
      } else {
          ans = pathRight;
      }
      ans.add(board[yPos][xPos]);      
      paths.get(yPos).set(xPos,ans);
      pathLength[yPos][xPos] = ans.size();
      return ans;    
  }

  private void getSequence() {
     ArrayList<Integer> result;
     pathLength = new int[maxX + 1][maxY + 1];
     paths = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>>();
     for(int y = 0; y <= maxY; y++)
     {
         ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> line = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();       
         for(int x = 0; x <= maxX; x++)
         {
             line.add(null);
             pathLength[y][x] = -1;
         }
         paths.add(line);
     }
     result = findSequence(0, 0);
     Collections.reverse(result);
     for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
       System.out.println(result.get(i));
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SnakeSequence sequence = new SnakeSequence();
    sequence.getSequence();        
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Recursive solution :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MaximumLengthSnakeSequence {

    static int max = -1;
    static List<Integer> maxListTemp = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int count = 0;
        int n = 4;
        int m = 4;

        int mat[][] = { { 9, 6, 5, 2 }, { 8, 7, 6, 5 }, { 7, 3, 1, 6 }, { 1, 1, 1, 7 }, };
        List<Integer> maxList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
                list.add(mat[i][j]);
                List<Integer> testList = recur(i, j, count, mat, n, m, list);
                if (maxList.size() < testList.size()) {
                    maxList = new ArrayList<>(testList);
                }
                maxListTemp.clear();
            }
        }

            System.out.println("max is " + maxList);
    }

    static List<Integer> recur(int i, int j, int count, int mat[][], int n, int m, List<Integer> list) {
        int curData = mat[i][j];
        int rightData = 0;
        int downData = 0;
        if (j + 1 < n && i < m) {
            rightData = mat[i][j + 1];
            if (Math.abs(curData - rightData) == 1) {
                list.add(rightData);
                recur(i, j + 1, count + 1, mat, n, m, list);
                list.remove(list.size() - 1);
            }
        }

        if (count > max) {
            max = count;
        }
        if (maxListTemp.size() < list.size()) {
            maxListTemp = new ArrayList<>(list);
        }

        if (i + 1 < m && j < n) {
            downData = mat[i + 1][j];
            if (Math.abs(curData - downData) == 1) {
                list.add(downData);
                recur(i + 1, j, count + 1, mat, n, m, list);
                list.remove(list.size() - 1);
            }
        }

        return maxListTemp;
    }
}
```